# How to get the shortest rather than longest possible regex match with preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have string similar to this one:

```
{{something1}} something2 {{something3}} something4
```

How can I match only "something1" using the `preg_match()` function?

I tried:

```
preg_match("/\{\{(.*)\}\}/si",$content,$matches);
```

but this matched too much, returning

```
something1}} something2 {{something3
```

I tried adding `\b` to the pattern, but didn't get what I want that way either.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: that looks like some sort of improper json do you have control over the string before it gets to you ?

Comment: First Question. Properly asked. Upvoted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use non greedy modifier `?` :

```
preg_match("/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/si",$content,$matches);
             here --^
```

Answer (score 3):

a full answer - if our $var is:

```
STARTT 
FIRST KKK
SECOND KKK
```

1) In case we use:

```
$var = preg_replace('/STARTT(.*)KKK/', 'REPLACED-STRING', $var);
```

it will change everything from the STARTT to last KKK and Result will be:

```
REPLACED-STRING
```

2) In case we use:

```
$var = preg_replace('/STARTT(.*?)KKK/', 'REPLACED-STRING', $var);
```

Result will be:

```
REPLACED-STRING 
SECOND KKK
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match('|{{([^}]+)}}|si', $content, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Since the OP's closing "tag" is a double `}`, a single `}` may very well be allowed. The reluctant `.*?` is more appropriate as M42 suggested, IMO.

Comment: Both methods work equally as well. I prefer to use `[^` to be as specific as possible. I believe using .*? takes more steps than the above regex (though I'm not sure, will test later on), though negligible performance difference merely brings this down to syntax.

Comment: @Narek sorry I was thinking of preg_match_all -- I've corrected it now. Tested it and it works.