# Deleting text between two strings in php using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've been trying to remove a section of text from a string the sites betweem two tags. For example:

```
This is CROPSTART not very CROPEND cool.
```

...should become this...

```
This is cool.
```

This is the PHP I've tried and generally it works:

```
preg_replace('#\/\/CROPSTART[\s\S]+\/\/CROPEND#', '', $string);
```

However, when the string contains multiple "CROPEND" it crops everything from the CROPSTART to the last CROPEND. I would like it to only crop between the first CROPSTART and the *first* CROPEND.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks
Wonko

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899158/php-preg-replace-non-greedy-trouble

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the shortest rather than longest possible regex match with preg\_match()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5897478)

Comment: Yes, looks like a dupe to me, guilty as charged. That said, the answer provided here was succinct and clear to understand.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> However, when the string contains multiple "CROPEND" it crops everything from the CROPSTART to the last CROPEND.

This is because your `+` operator is greedy - it won't stop at the first instance of `CROPEND` and continue until it encounters the last instance.

You can use a non-greedy version of the `+` operator simply by appending a `?` after it:

```
preg_replace('/CROPSTART[\s\S]+?CROPEND/', '', $string);
```

Comment: How would it work if I have "CROPSTART FirstWord CROPEND only this CROPSTART SecWord CROPEND" and I want to get " only this "?