# How to remove specific content between two php tags from php file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to remove content between two php tags from a php file I tried many methods but not succeed please help here is an example code. I am getting garbage content in all of my php files due to some virus attack:

**Garbage Content in example.php**

```
<?php $xikcjche = '223}!+!<+{e%+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%!osvu<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%7-K ?>

 <?php
echo "here is my original code in this file";
?>
```

so I want to create a function that can remove the upper code i.e. garbage code,I tried this code :-

```
$file = file_get_contents("example_one.php");

$str = 'before-str-after';
preg_match('/before-(.*?)-after/', $str, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

it is not taking php tags `<?php` and `?>` and also if i use space between before and -str i am getting notices.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407850/deleting-text-between-two-strings-in-php-using-preg-replace, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031250/php-function-to-delete-all-between-certain-characters-in-string

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you use php tags inside preg_match rather than <script> tags or other html tags as shown in your given links,my motive is php tags.

Comment: Yes, you can, `'/' . preg_quote("<?php", "/") . '(.*?)' . preg_quote("?>", "/") . '/s'` should work.

Comment: `preg_replace('/<\?php(?:(?!<\?php).)*/s', '', $file)` [See it here](https://regex101.com/r/foW8TX/1)