# PHP: Regex replace everything between to strings/HTML tags

Tags: php, regex

I have the below text but want the quote bit removed from the string, I'm using the below regex but it gives me the below error.

**Text Example 1**

```
<p>[quote]</p>
<p>[quote]</p>
<p>inner quote text</p>
<p>[/quote]</p>
<p>outer quote text</p>
<p>[/quote]</p>
<p>This is a test.</p>
```

**Text Example 2**

```
<p>[quote][quote]</p>
<p>inner quote text</p>
<p>[/quote]</p>
<p>outer quote text</p>
<p>[/quote]</p>
<p>This is a test.</p>
```

**Expected Text**

```
<p>This is a test.</p>
```

**Regex**

```
preg_replace('/<p>\[quote\][\s\S]+?<p>\[\/quote\]<\/p>/', '', $string);
```

**Error**

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset
```

I've had a look at [Deleting text between two strings in php using preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407850/deleting-text-between-two-strings-in-php-using-preg-replace) which has helped but I haven't been able to figure it out, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should be the resulting text?

Comment: 1.) the error says you haven't escaped `[` in ...`\<p\>[`...2.) your sample text contains `[quote` and not `[quote]`. Further there is no need to escape `<`,`>`

Comment: @mrzasa, sorry, updated the question now.

Comment: This tool will help you testing your regex (with great explanations): https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because you've not escaped an opening `[` character in your regular expression. Please see the `[` I have marked below:

```
preg_replace('/\<p\>\[quote\]\<\/p\>[\s\S]+?\<p\>[\/quote\]\<\/p\>/', '', $string);
                                                 ^
```

This has resulted in starting a character class that has not been closed. You should simply escape this opening brace like this:

```
preg_replace('/\<p\>\[quote\]\<\/p\>[\s\S]+?\<p\>\[\/quote\]\<\/p\>/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting text from HTML is tricky, so the best option is to use a library like Html2Text. It was built specifically for this purpose.

https://github.com/mtibben/html2text

Install using composer:

composer require html2text/html2text
Basic usage:

```
$html = new \Html2Text\Html2Text('<p>[quote</p>test piece of text<p>[/quote]</p>This is a test.');

echo $html->getText();  // test piece of text This is a test.
```

OR you can use simply the function PHP strip_tags

string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

http://php.net/strip_tags

```
echo str_replace("[/quote]","",str_replace("[quote","",strip_tags("<p>
[quote</p>
test piece of text
<p>[/quote]</p>
This is a test.")));
```